# How to make "Most Popular" with parse iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, parsing, backend

In my project the user submits a story and I am trying to place this the most looked at on a "popular page" but have not found a way to do it. Here is my code so far thanks in advance and yes I know its not much but anything helps.

MasterViewContoller.m

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // Customize the table

        // The className to query on
        self.className = @"Word";

        // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
        self.textKey = @"by";

        // Uncomment the following line to specify the key of a PFFile on the PFObject to display in the imageView of the default cell style
        // self.imageKey = @"image";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        self.paginationEnabled = YES;

        // The number of objects to show per page
        self.objectsPerPage = 25;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Cloud Code

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Word", function(request, response) {

var wordText = request.Object.get("wordText");
var attribution = request.Object.get("by");

if(wordText.length){

    if (attribution.length){

            response.success();

            }else{

            request.object.set("by", "annoymous");
            response.success();
    }

    }else{
    response.error("Not valid. Please fill in all text");
}

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create another key in the "Word" object with an int type, (for example, let's call it, `timesViewed`) so that every time a `PFUser` that is not the `currentUser` views the object, `timesViewed` increases by one. Then query for `timesViewed` with `[query orderByDescending:@"timesViewed]`.

Comment: In the cloud code you should add the timesViewed object. So let's say the code to create a new "Word" class object is like this: `PFObject *word = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Word"];`  `[word setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"by"];`   `//set to 0 as initial value``[word setObject:0 forKey:@"timesViewed"];`

Comment: You can also edit you're previously created class objects straight from the parse data browser. If in your database the `timesViewed` object exists, then just put 0, but if it doesn't, create a new row, name it and put in values. To test it out, you can place different values through the data browser

Comment: No problem thank you. Im still confused on how how timesViewed would pull from the NewPostedPage and how I would do that and How would timesViewed send to send to the other devices ill post what I have in my cloud code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33055/discussion-between-luke-and-aj-s)